# Symfony 3 | FOSCommentBundle manage many Threads / Comments

Tags: comments, symfony, foscommentbundle

I use FOSCommentBundle in my project, I already configured it with a thread and a comment class and this is working.
But now I need to manage many types of thread and comment.

For example I have News with comments and I have Contents with comments.
Of course, the news comments are different from content comments.

I don't know how to do it in the config.yml :

```
fos_comment:
    db_driver: orm
    class:
        model:
            comment: Project\MyBundle\Entity\News
            thread: Project\MyBundle\Entity\Comment
```

How can I add my other thread / comment type ? Or how can I manage this case ?

TY

Answer (score 0):

In the template that you want to use FOSCommentBundle you have to put thi code:

```
{% include 'FOSCommentBundle:Thread:async.html.twig' with {'id': 'foo'} %}
```

So in the part `{'id':'foo'}` you can put a different id for any thread you want, even a different thread for any news, for example

```
{% include 'FOSCommentBundle:Thread:async.html.twig' with {'id': 'news'~news.id} %}
```

Comment: Hi @REDMAN, Thanks for your answer. I posted my question on the GitHub repo : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/issues/567 and somebody answered me approximately the same answer. I have to use only one table with different id in function of comment type.

For example I have to do one table "Comment" with a field "ThreadId" = news-1 / news-2 / content-1 / content-2 and that's not what I want. I really need two different comment tables, one with "NewsId" and the other one with "ContentId". I didn't find a way so I gave up weeks ago. TY